# TouchDown event is delayed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-7, touch

My application uses the `UiElement.TouchDown` event in various places, one of them is to let the user stop a spinning wheel. In this situation, one can easily notice a short delay of about 1/3s between the actual touching of the screen and the TouchDown event.

I have set `Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled` to false.

In order to troubleshoot this problem, I've written a test tool that reports WPF events and native window messages, and I noticed that as soon as I touched the screen, messages with id 0x02CC, 0x011B and 0x011A are generated, about 100 to 300 ms before the TouchDown event. This leads me to believe that the drivers report the touch quickly, and the delay is introduced somewhere later in the WPF translations.

Is there a way to make the touch interaction more responsive? Please ask for any information you need!

Comment: The driver itself send the data very fast to windows events, but windows is slowing everything... you can check the delay if you open MSPaint, and draw fast, the line you are drawing is not under your finger, there is a little lag.... and I don't think we can do something to this because of windows... maybe I'm wrong

Comment: This may be connected, but I don't believe that this is the case here. If I immediately lift my finger after touching, both TouchDown and TouchUp are raised simultniously and more quickly than the single TouchDown before.

Comment: Our team is talking about this delay problem to ELO and 3M programer, and this is what they told us... the touchup is fast because windows have nothing to do on the up event, on the touchdown windows check is there is a gesture and everyting... if we want something faster, we need to talk directly to the driver, not by windows event...

Answer (score 2):

Unless Flicks are needed set both in XAML or by manually setting in code behind: (I assume you meant to say IsPressAndHoldEnabled not IsTouchAndHoldEnabled)

```
Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled="False" Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled="False"
```

Furthermore consider handling the TouchDown Event and also capturing it to the relevant UIElement (don't forget to release it in TouchUp).

```
uielement.CaptureTouch(e.TouchDevice);
e.Handled = true;
```